# Why are Kakyoin and Polnareff so pleased about knowing the same hand signals?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

In episode 24 of *JoJo's Bizarre Adventure: Stardust Crusaders*, Polnareff takes advantage of a dangerous situation to show off his knowledge of hand signals. A video of this can be found [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRsXY1GYmSE).

Kakyoin recognises the hand signal as meaning "Your underwear is showing", which greatly pleases Polnareff. The two of them share some kind of elaborate handshake to mark the occasion, the eyes of both characters being darkened (which, as far as I understand, usually indicates seriousness).

What on Earth is going on here? Why do Kakyoin and Polnareff know this, why is Polnareff so pleased and why do they share an elaborate hand shake afterwards?

Comment: I haven't seen the video, but I think it's more of them being pleased about "Your panties are showing", and their handshake signifies their camaraderie (in perverseness).

Comment: @nhahtdh In the video, the only people nearby are JoJo, Jotaro, Avdol, and of course Kakyoin and Polnareff - none of whoms underwear is showing. He does it to show off his knowledge of the hand signal, not as a practical application of it.

Comment: i always thought Polnareff was charading the phrase "I see London, I see France, I see someone's underpants"
Because the triangle-shaped hand signal can mean the Eiffel Tower, and he makes binocular hands as well just my opinion thought it was funny

Answer (score 9):

Polnareff knows this by virtue of him being Polnareff.

Combining the individual gestures and their 'translations' makes the sentence that it does.

Pan (Japanese sound for clapping) + 2 (two) + ok (maru) + seeing something (mieru) = pan-tsu (underwear) + maru (entire) + mieru (can see)

Only Kakyoin is able to decipher what he's trying to say, since NO ONE ELSE chimes in, and they both share a bonding moment. That bonding moment is the amazing handshake, and their eyes darken to reflect the solemnity of the bro-ment.

Comment: So the handshake is just an awesome, improvised handshake, and nothing more?

Comment: Yep. Is it cool? Hell yeah it is. @DrRDizzle

Answer (score 7):

It's also a reference to another manga series called Dr. Slump, where another character does the same hand signal. So it could be a bro moment where Polnareff is basically going "Whoa, you got that reference? Yeeeesss, we read the same comic!"

It might also be worth noting that France loves manga, so it would make sense that Polnareff had read Dr. Slump.

Comment: i mean, it could work, but it's not really that.
pretty cool tho